# While deploying a web application ,facing a struts error

Tags: java, xml, servlets, struts

I am deploying a web application on the server and I get the below error. 
 Could you plz help me come out this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Missing configuration /WEB- INF/struts-config1.xml
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.splitAndResolvePaths
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)


java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.
at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:755)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:735)


web.xml 
<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>config</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml, /WEB-INF/struts-config1.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Comment: Is the file actually there? Did you cut-and-paste the XML from a web page, as the error includes an extra space `WEB- INF` instead of `WEB-INF` for the second file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one Struts configuration file (`struts-config.xml`) in the `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>config</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```